# Can I use the G2 Pedal to simply act as a volume pedal?

Tags: guitar, guitar-effects, effects-pedal, dynamics

I have access to a Guitar Effects Pedal G2 by Zoom (https://www.zoom-na.com/sites/default/files/products/downloads/pdfs/G2.pdf) and I've been perusing the manual for a distortion-free volume amplification (and reset) via one of the buttons.  I want to press the button to increase volume for a solo then press again to return to the previous volume.

I'm either missing something very obvious or the G2 is too advanced for such a simple operation.  I know I could just buy a volume pedal but I'm trying to make do with what I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a couple options for this, at least.  Using the Compressor, you can use the makeup gain to add additional volume without actually compressing the signal.  It could be a good idea to add some compression anyway, so this seems like a good approach.  I'm not too sure but I believe you could also use the Booster to increase your volume, however, it appears that this is intended for boosting specific frequency ranges, so it may not work perfectly for you.  Beyond that, the distortions have a Level setting, so you could use an overdrive at very low gain (to prevent excessive distortion), then use the Level control to increase the output volume.

Comment: Using boost is probably right for solos, as you do want to boost highs more than lows, generally

Comment: @DrMayhem I'd agree, at least in many situations.  Adding some mids and/or highs will give you more presence in the mix of things without actually increasing your overall volume too drastically.  It just needs to be done tastefully enough that it's not going to cause some ear piercing sounds.

Comment: But some overdrive could accomplish that as well, since distortion is essentially just adding harmonics to your sound, ie, higher frequencies that would increase your presence.